# Mouse input causes system to hang when in fullscreen mode (20.04)

Tags: mouse, 20.04, fullscreen

When moving the mouse in a fullscreen application (tested in Counterstrike Global Offensive, Factorio, YouTube), the mouse movement speed decreases and feels "sloshy" (i.e. it feels a bit like hardware acceleration is on to an almost comical degree), and the system holds a freeze frame until mouse movement stops.

I have rebooted several times and the problem persists, I'm not sure what logs I should provide to help debug this. Please let me know and I will grab them!